# PDFsharp DrawString Text Invisible for certain PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

The system I am working on stamps PDF's with certain information. It does this by creating a lime green text box in the top right corner of the document. It then draws a certain string on top of the green space. This works for thousands of PDFs but for one the text is invisible even though the box is drawn. I can still select the text and copy it to something else, but it is invisible in the PDF.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the PDF but it is a PDF 1.4. What would cause this?

The code for stamping:

```
    private static XGraphics drawString(XGraphics xgr, PdfPage page, string printString, int pageNumber = 0)
    {
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 10, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

        var textSize = xgr.MeasureString(printString, font);
        var width = textSize.Width;
        var height = textSize.Height;

        double xMin = 0;
        double yMin = 0;

        if (page.Rotate == 90)
        {
            xMin = page.Height - textSize.Width;
            var state = xgr.Save();
            xgr.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.LimeGreen, xMin, yMin, width, height);
            xgr.Restore(state);
            xgr.DrawString(printString, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Height, page.Width), topRight()); 
        }
        else 
        {
            xMin = page.Width - textSize.Width;
            var state = xgr.Save();
            xgr.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.LimeGreen, xMin, yMin, width, height);
            xgr.Restore(state);
            xgr.DrawString(printString, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height), topRight()); 
        }

        return xgr;
    }

    private static XStringFormat topRight()
    {
        XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
        format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Far;
        format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;
        return format;
    }
```

I have tried using Dipose() on xgr and reinitialising it before each of its draw actions. I have tried saving and restoring the state of xgr between draw actions as seen in the code. I have tried various fonts and font sizes with no luck either.

Let me know what metadata about the PDF is relevant and I will share that.

Answer (score 1):

Using PdfSharp 1.5 GDI, I have been having this issue as well.  Some pdfs would be ok, others would have 1 or 2 pages that were ok, and then others would have no pages that were ok.  Text could be selected, but text could not be seen. Changing the renderMode fixes the issue.

In PdfGraphicsState.cs, there is a condition to check if _realizedRenderingMode != renderMode.  However, _realizedRenderingMode and renderMode is 0 by default, so it never enters codeblock, nor does it look like there is a method for changing the renderMode unless you change the font to italic, bold, strikeout, or underline:

```
    int _realizedRenderingMode;  // Reference: TABLE 5.2  Text state operators / Page 398

    public void RealizeFont(XFont font, XBrush brush, int renderingMode)
    {
        const string format = Config.SignificantFigures3;

        // So far rendering mode 0 (fill text) and 2 (fill, then stroke text) only.
        RealizeBrush(brush, _renderer._colorMode, renderingMode, font.Size); // _renderer.page.document.Options.ColorMode);

        // Realize rendering mode.
        if (_realizedRenderingMode != renderingMode)
        {
            _renderer.AppendFormatInt("{0} Tr\n", renderingMode);
            _realizedRenderingMode = renderingMode;
        }
```

Removing the condition would suffice in fixing the issue, but the renderingMode seems to only be needed 1 time for the BT (Begin Text) in XGraphicsPdfRenderer.cs.

```
    internal void BeginTextMode()
    {
        if (_streamMode != StreamMode.Text)
        {
            _streamMode = StreamMode.Text;
            _content.Append("BT\n");
            // Text matrix is empty after BT
            _gfxState.RealizedTextPosition = new XPoint();
            _gfxState.ItalicSimulationOn = false;
        }
    }
```

So, I ended up modifying XGraphics to include XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions and passing the variable to the various methods so it can be changed regardless of location:

```
    private XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions _renderOptions { get; set; }
    public XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions RenderOptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_renderOptions == null)
            {
                _renderOptions = new XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions();
            }

            return _renderOptions;
        }
        set
        {
            _renderOptions = value;
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind that the renderMode is originally based on whether the font is italic, bold, strikeout, or underline, which I don't really see how those relate to renderMode, in XGraphicsPdfRenderer.cs:

```
            //bool bold = (font.Style & XFontStyle.Bold) != 0;
        //bool italic = (font.Style & XFontStyle.Italic) != 0;
        bool italicSimulation = (font.GlyphTypeface.StyleSimulations & XStyleSimulations.ItalicSimulation) != 0;
        bool boldSimulation = (font.GlyphTypeface.StyleSimulations & XStyleSimulations.BoldSimulation) != 0;
        bool strikeout = (font.Style & XFontStyle.Strikeout) != 0;
        bool underline = (font.Style & XFontStyle.Underline) != 0;

        Realize(font, brush, boldSimulation ? 2 : 0);
```

Class and enum:

```
public class XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions
{
    public XGraphicsPdfRenderMode RenderMode { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeRenderModeForPage { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeRenderModeForObject { get; set; }
}

public enum XGraphicsPdfRenderMode
{
    Text_Render_Mode_Fill = 0,
    Text_Render_Mode_Stroke = 1,
    Text_Render_Mode_Fill_Stroke = 2,
    Text_Render_Mode_Invisible = 3
}
```

Usage:

```
gfx.RenderOptions = new XGraphicsPdfRendererOptions() { RenderMode = XGraphicsPdfRenderMode.Text_Render_Mode_Fill, IncludeRenderModeForPage = true };
```

https://github.com/zaryk/PDFsharp

Answer (score 1):

I've happened across this issue a couple of times now on separate projects. I found that the simplest fix is to dispose of the `XGraphics` object and then simply re-instantiate it using your current `PdfPage` instance.

```
 PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage Page = Document.AddPage();

 PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics gfx = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Page);

 //Build your pdf here until transparency issue occurs

 //Issue has occured so re-instantiate gfx object
 gfx.Dispose();
 gfx = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(Page);

 //Continue as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I use to hide something in document and edit the document and again save. Let me know if it helps you

```
private PdfDocument FormatPdfDocument(PdfDocument document, List<string> packingTypes, string carrierName)
{
    XFont PackingTypeFont = new XFont("Calibri", 10, XFontStyle.Bold);
    var i = 0;
    foreach (PdfPage page in document.Pages)
    {
        using (var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page))
        {
            var packingType = packingTypes.ElementAtOrDefault(i++) ?? "PackingType Not Found";
            if (carrierName == "xxxx")
            {
                var packingTypeBounds = new XRect(64, 62, 200, 12);
                gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.White, packingTypeBounds);
                gfx.DrawString(packingType, PackingTypeFont, XBrushes.Black, packingTypeBounds, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

                var logoBounds = new XRect(0, 0, 130, 50);
                gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.White, logoBounds);
            }
            else if (carrierName == "yyyy")
            {
                var packingTypeBounds = new XRect(200, 0, 200, 12);
                gfx.DrawString(packingType, PackingTypeFont, XBrushes.Black, packingTypeBounds, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
            }
            else if (carrierName == "zzzz")
            {
                var packingTypeBounds = new XRect(410, 20, 200, 12);
                var state = gfx.Save();
                gfx.RotateAtTransform(90, new XPoint { X = 410, Y = 20 });
                gfx.DrawString(packingType, PackingTypeFont, XBrushes.Black, packingTypeBounds, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
                gfx.Restore(state);
            }
        }
    }    
    return document;
}
```

This works fine for me till date without any issues

Comment: This does not help me. My green rectangle is drawn fine on the PDF in question but my string is not. My code has worked on thousands of PDFs so I don't need this code. Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes to answer your question "What would cause this?":

Are you using the latest version PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3b?
IIRC there is a bug in 1.32 that can lead to unexpected behavior because some properties are not reset.
Since you see the rectangle this might be the cause.

Since you see the rectangle, this probably does not apply:
There are two ways of modifying existing pages: "append" and "prepend". Your code snippet does not show how you do it.
With "prepend" your lime rectangle could be hidden under a white filled rectangle. Watch the PDF in Adobe Reader with active Transparency Grid and check that you see the grid where the rectangle should be.

Since you see the rectangle, this probably does not apply:
Maybe your text goes to the wrong position. Check the MediaBox and CropBox settings of the PDF page you are modifying. Normally pages start at (0,0), but you cannot be sure.
Locate your text in the PDF file and compare the text position with MediaBox and CropBox.

It could be an unknown bug in PDFsharp. If you do not find a PDF that allows to replicate the issue which you can share then it will be very difficult to fix the bug. But maybe one of the options above leads to success.

Comment: I did try using the 1.50 beta with no change. The MediaBox and CropBox are correct. Thank you for the other suggestions. If I find a PDF with same problem which I can share I will.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find a way to make it work. I ran the stamping process twice on the document and it worked as expected. Fortunately, stamping twice does not affect regular documents which actually work normally.

Comment: Sounds like a hack. How "secret" is the PDF? Is it possible that you send it to the developers of PDFsharp for an internal review only? I understand you found a workaround - all files get two stamps even though only one file out of 1000 needs it. In the worst case this workaround will still be the best option after a review, but I'd like to know whether or not PDFsharp has a bug here.

Comment: It absolutely it is a hack! But I will have to go with it for now. Unfortunately I really cannot share it. I apologize that I cannot help PDFsharp out here.

Answer (score 0):

Still an issue in 1.50 for some PDF files...
As a workaround, I create a PNG file using System.Drawing.DrawString.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)p.Width.Point, 30);
Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
gra.DrawString("Hello world", new Font("Verdana", 20), Brushes.Red, new PointF(0, 0));
bmp.Save("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Then I use XGraphics.DrawImage from this PNG file.

```
XGraphics xg = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(p, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
XImage xi = XImage.FromFile("test.png");
// Add it at the bottom of the page
xg.DrawImage(xi, 0, p.Height-32, p.Width, 30);
```

This always ends up on top.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).